# IBM Domino and Java 8

Tags: xpages, lotus-domino

I'm developing XPages applications with **IBM Domino 9.0.1 FP4** which uses an out-dated JVM with **Java 6**. This limitation is frequently forcing me to create Java apps outside of the Domino environment and run them in a secondary up-to-date JVM that is located on the same computer as the Domino server. This "solution" works but is far from being optimal. Hence I have two questions:

A) **Is it possible to manually update the Domino JVM?**

B) **If not, is there an easier solution to use Java 7 or 8 with the current Domino version?**

---

*Personal note*: I know that one of the "next" Domino versions is supposed to feature Java 8. However, it is (at least to me) unclear when this release will happen. I have been waiting for an update of the Domino JVM for at least 1 or 2 years now and I have stopped believing that this will happen anytime soon...

Comment: This year will see new stuff in Notes

Comment: 9.0.1FP9 still does not include Java 8 in Designer. http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/fixlist.nsf/4/12d957b7c277fc728525816300434c53?OpenDocument

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't manually update the JVM. If you want to use different Java versions, you need to use the [Crossworlds](https://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/CrossWorlds) project. Danielle used it with the Websphere Liberty profile, while I use that approach with the [vert.x](http://vertx.io) framework for my ProjectCastle.

You can read about my experience with Domino and vert.x [on my blog](http://www.notessensei.com/blog/categories/vert.x.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. After taking a quick look at the CrossWorlds presentation and your blog entries about vert.x, I think this is exactly what I am looking for... yet it feels like using a sledgehammer to crack a nut :)

Comment: Interesting info. I read up on it a bit. I got the impression that... can you confirm... Websphere Liberty is free?!

Comment: @RichardSchwartz for certain scenarios Liberty is free. Details here: https://developer.ibm.com/wasdev/docs/websphere-application-server-everyone/

Comment: Thanks. That's actually pretty clear for IBM licensing info ;-)